# How to create path using execution date in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have the following Airflow dag:

```
    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)

    gcs_export_uri_template = 'adstest/2018/08/31/*'
    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery',
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='CSV',
        source_objects=[gcs_export_uri_template],
        schema_fields=dc(),
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        skip_leading_rows = 1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
    )

start_task >> update_bigquery
```

This dag load data from `adstest/2018/08/31/*` to BigQuery and it works great.

I want to modify the Dag to run over dates based on `execution date`:

```
Execution date
Execution date - 1 days
Execution date - 2 days
```

Example if Execution date is `2018-09-02` I want the DAG to go to:

```
Execution date : adstest/2018/09/02/*
Execution date - 1 days : adstest/2018/09/01/*
Execution date - 2 days : adstest/2018/08/31/*
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
This is my updated code:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    gcs_export_uri_template = ['''adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -{0}), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*'''.format(i)]
    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}'.format(i),
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='CSV',
        source_objects=gcs_export_uri_template,
        schema_fields=dc(),
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
    )
    start_task >> update_bigquery
```

**Edit 2:**

My code:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    gcs_export_uri_template = ['''adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*'''.format(i)]

    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}'.format(i),
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='CSV',
        source_objects=gcs_export_uri_template,
        schema_fields=dc(),
        params={'i': i},
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
    )
```

Template:
[image]

The code gives this error:

```
"Source URI must not contain the ',' character: gs://adstest/{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }/*">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Airflow Macros](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#id13) to achieve this as follows:

```py
gcs_export_uri_template=[
    "adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(ds, '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*",
    "adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(prev_ds, '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*",
    "adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -2), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*"
]

update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
    source_format='CSV',
    source_objects=gcs_export_uri_template,
    schema_fields=dc(),
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
)
```

When you run the above code, you can check in the Web UI, the rendered parameter:

[image: Airflow Macros Date]

---

**For EDITED Comment**:

You will need to pass the value of the loop variable `i` in `params` parameter and use it in the string as `params.i` as follows:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    gcs_export_uri_template = ["adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*"]
    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}'.format(i),
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='CSV',
        source_objects=gcs_export_uri_template,
        schema_fields=dc(),
        params={'i': i},
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
    )
    start_task >> update_bigquery
```

Comment: Assuming I'll need range of dates and I'm creating the operator in loop for `index in range(50, 0, -1): `  Can I do something like `"adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, ? ), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*" `  - Replaceing the ? with the loop `index`  ?

Comment: Also I have an issue about format.. your code gives me the day and month in 1 digit... 1 and not 01 , 8 and not 08

Comment: As I showed in the screenshot it gives me `01` for day and month both. Not really sure why you don't get it.

Comment: @Programmer120 Added solution for your Loop variable issue

Comment: doesn't work - "Source URI must not contain the ',' character: gs://adstest/{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }/*">

Comment: Did you add the `params` parameter to the operator? If yes, please post the screenshot of what you see in "Rendered" field in the UI. I tested the code, works fine for me.

Comment: Aah.. I know the issue.. Sry, I left `.format(i)` which is not required. Can you check my updated comment, it should work now.

Comment: sweet it works. Is there also a way for the operator to print into log his own `"adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*" `   I'm creating 5 operators each one has different path..