# Airflow override 'ds' within macro function

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, airflow

I'm trying to pass a dynamic date value into a macro function ds_format.

```
DEFAULT_DATE= '{{ ds }}'
__init__(self, exec_date=DEFAULT_DATE): self.exec_date = exec_date
```

Now, I've some macros within the functions like

```
{{macros.ds_format(ds, "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d")}}
```

But, I want to pass the exec_date into the macro like

```
"""{{ macros.ds_format(""" + self.exec_date + """, "%Y-%m-%d", "%d%m%Y") }}"""
```

Is this the right way to pass a value to to a micro in Airflow (jinja2) ? or. Is there a different way to pass the dynamic value (exec_date) ?.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just pass as follow:

```
"""{{ macros.ds_format(ds, "%Y-%m-%d", "%d%m%Y") }}"""
```

An example is https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137676/5691525

**Edited**:

Why don't you use the following code if you just want to use exectiuon date:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ execution_date.strftime('"%d%m%Y"') }}"
```

If you want to just use variable why even use jinja at all? Just use normal python `datetime` that can be seen in this post: [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Comment: Thanks for the update. My question was how to pass the a dynamic variable self.exec_date into the ds_format function ?

Comment: Updated the comment

Comment: I may redefine the original question. Here, my requirement is to pass the {{ execution_date }} or {{ ds }} to a different class (without using PythonOperator) as an argument within the constructor and then use it. So, In simple, I want to pass the Jinja template to a class or Need to find a way to retrieve the execution date without using Jinja templates now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simpler to just use the {{ ds_nodash }} instead?

https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros